# Alexa doesn't accept AMAZON.US_LAST_NAME slotType when importing from Lex

Tags: amazon-web-services, alexa-skills-kit, amazon-lex

I have built a bot in Lex, and I use the `AMAZON.US_LAST_NAME` slot type for one of my slots.

But when I exported from Lex into the Alexa JSON format, and then imported into Alexa, the import fails because `AMAZON.US_LAST_NAME` slot type is not recognized/used by Alexa.

The differences between Lex and Alexa surprise me more and more with each one I discover.

The [**Lex documentation on slot types**](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lex/latest/dg/howitworks-builtins-slots.html) even refer us to the Alexa slot types:

> For a list of available built-in slot types, see the [**Slot Type Reference**](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/custom-skills/slot-type-reference.html) in the Alexa Skills Kit documentation.

So to discover that there is a difference between them is more than strange. Does anyone know why this is?

Or if anyone has come across this, what would be the workaround for getting Alexa to have a similar `US_LAST_NAMES` slot type?

Answer (score 1):

I think you could use `AMAZON.Person` slot type.

Comment: That might work, thanks for the suggestion, would have to test a lot to make sure that it correctly understands average people's names and not try to match to a famous person too much. Also would prefer to keep my current setup of 2 slots: first_name and last_name, so would have to test if it accepts only last names appropriately. I'm afraid it would try to inject a first name into my last_name slot though.